# How to use forwardAuth with internal service in Traefik?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

Traefik allows to specify a middleware to authenticate each request using `forwardAuth`, in the documentation it specifies to use an external provider.

```yaml
# Forward authentication to example.com
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: test-auth
spec:
  forwardAuth:
    address: https://example.com/auth
```

I have an auth server running inside my k8 cluster itself which I want to use instead on an external service, is there a way to use `forwardAuth` to point to internal service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used K8 Fully Qualified Domain Name as the address for this to work:

`service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local`.